# Null Validation for list?

Tags: java, validation, exception, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to add `validation` for my `ArrayList` if it is `null`, below is my current implementation:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>():

if(personList!=null){

//do something

}
```

However, this still throws an `exception` If the list is deemed to be null, how can I fix this?

Comment: add the complete stacktrace

Comment: What is `validation`? The expression `new ArrayList<>()` can never return null.

Comment: you are already initializing the personList , it will never be null

Comment: are you sure it's happening in these codelines? doesn't seem likely

Comment: is the exception inside the `//do something` code? If it is, what is said code? A `List` can be not null but still be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `(personList!= null) && !personList.isEmpty()` in your code.

```
 if((personList!= null) && !personList.isEmpty())

    //do something

 }
```

now it will never throw null pointer exception.

Comment: Please use `!personList.isEmpty()` instead of checking its size.

Comment: if `personList` would be null this would create a NullPointerException, even if it is unlikely, that you get a NullPointerException if the Arralist is created just before it, but this i not a null check

Comment: @LuckAss It isn't just unlikely, it is impossible. You never get null from `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: @marstran yeah that's right, it's just in case this is not the ful code, as it sems to be, so if he's calling some method or doing something with the arraylist before, it could be possible that it's null ;) since he wanted a check for null

Answer (score 0):

The list is not null, since you have initialized it. It will be an emptylist in your case. You should check for `personList.isEmpty()`

`List<Person> personList = null` will return true for null check

Answer (score 0):

This statement creates an array list, which is definitely not null.

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>():
```

So check if the list is not empty:

```
if(!personList.isEmpty())
```

or

```
if(personList.size() != 0)
```